# How can I handle multiple requests at the same time in Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I'm currently writing an API in which a user could transfer money from their account to a phone but I'm facing an issue which is the user can call the API more than once at the same time and ask for transferring the money. Normally the balance of his account wouldn't be correct after the calls so I searched a lot and found out that I can use atomic transactions and lock the database. Now if the user uses the API for example twice, one of them runs correctly but the other one gets `django.db.utils.OperationalError: database is locked` error. Any idea how can I handle both of them correctly? (I could use a **while** and wait until the database gets unlocked but I rather don't do that)

> models.py

```
@transaction.atomic()
    def withdraw(self, amount, phone, username):
        property = transferLog.objects.filter(username=username).order_by('-time').select_for_update()[0]
        if property.property >= int(amount):
            self.username = username
            self.property = property.property - int(amount)
            self._from = username
            self._to = phone
            self.amount = int(amount)
            self.time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
            self.save()
            return {'result': 'success', 'message': 'transfer complete', 'remaining': self.property}
        else:
            return {'result': 'error', 'message': 'not enough money'}
```

Comment: You should probably move from SQLite to another database provider, like PostgreSQL. SQLite does not support a very high level of concurrency,

Comment: Yes, I changed the database and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using SQLite database. It doesn't allow concurrent writes, i.e. more than one writing operations at a given time.

You have to options:

1. Either switch to a different database
2. Or increase the database `timeout` option in settings

Example:

```py
# settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'timeout': 60, # 1 minute
        }
    }
}
```

This is not a scalable solution. Suppose, you've got many processes waiting for the write access, you may still get `OperationalError` if there are any processes still waiting after 60 seconds.

Comment: I increased the timeout. The error was gone but the balance didn't change. I think I should move to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Mfr Hard to say. Did you try to debug the code. Is it working as expected? But yeah, if your project requires concurrent writes, then it's best to ditch SQLite.

Comment: yes, I'm debugging it for hours :) You're right, SQLite isn't suitable for me. Thanks anyway!